# invalidate a validation from a nested schema virtual mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have my parent schema defined like this:

**User.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PasswordSchema = require('./Password');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    password: PasswordSchema
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My children schema defined like this:

**Password.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var crypto = require('crypto');

var PasswordSchema = new Schema ({
    _id: false,
    hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
    salt: { type: String, default: '' }
});

var passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,24}$/;

PasswordSchema.virtual('password')
    .set(function (password) {
        if (passwordRegex.test(password))
        {
             this.invalidate('password', 'Invalid password format');
        }
     });

mongoose.model('Password', PasswordSchema);
module.exports = PasswordSchema;
```

Now I used these Models schema in my controller like this:

**user.js:**

```
require('../models/User');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var Password = mongoose.model('Password');

router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    var password = new Password({ password: 'abcd1234' });
    console.log(password.$__.validationError.errors['hashedPassword']); // Here it works I got the validation error
    user.password = password;
    user.password.$__.validationError = password.$__.validationError; // WORKAROUND
    console.log(user.password.$__.validationError.errors['hashedPassword']); // Here it doesn't work no validation error anymore ... 
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(":(");
        else
            console.log(":)");
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Question:**
So my problem now is that no matter what password I send to my children virtual it doesn't invalidate the process. How could I invalidate the mongoose save action from a children virtual ? Is there an other better option ?

**Question Updated:**
In user.js why the variable password has the validation error and when I assign it to user.password I don't have the validation error anymore ? How can I correct it ?

** Update 2:**
I have found a workaround see user.js: I just assign the required property to generate validation error. But it looks really not clean is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one good example https://gist.github.com/swaj/1350041, refactor it as below

```
PasswordSchema.virtual('password')
    .get(function(){
        return this._password;
    })
    .set(function (password) {
        this._password = password;
        // invoke crypto to hash and encrypt password, then assign it to hashedPassword
        this.hashedPassword = password; // this is just for test
     });

PasswordSchema.path('hashedPassword').validate(function(v) {
    if (v) {
        if (passwordRegex.test(v)) {
            this.invalidate('password', 'Invalid password format');
        }
    }
    if (!v) {
        this.validate('password', 'password required');
    }
}, null);
```

Test codes

```
var user = new User({name: 'dd'});
user.password = new Password({password: 'asdfASF123444'});
user.save(function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log("save user successfully");
});
```

Validation error is

```
{ [ValidationError: User validation failed]
  message: 'User validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { password:
      { [ValidatorError: Invalid password format]
        properties: [Object],
        message: 'Invalid password format',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        kind: 'user defined',
        path: 'password',
        value: undefined } } }
```

---

Per [`invalidate` source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/801b1a6cf41bf62e5c27d948a697793133a9f2af/lib/document.js#L1007)

```
Document.prototype.invalidate = function (path, err, val) {
  if (!this.$__.validationError) {
    this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
  }
  // ...
```

We know `invalidate` function belong to `Document`.

```
 password.$__.validationError.errors['hashedPassword']
```

You define the `validation` for `PasswordSchema`, not in `UserSchema`. so `user.password.$__.validationError.errors['hashedPassword']` is not valid.

---

Test your code with

```
var user = new User({name: 'dd'});
user.password = new Password({password: 'asdfwe32113'});
user.save(function (err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log("save user successfully");
});
```

Validation will be triggered, however, with this code

```
`user.password = new Password({hashedPassword: 'asdfwe32113'});`
```

This validation is NOT triggered.

Because for [`virtual` field](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), only the correct virtual name field is updated then the `.set` function could be called.

Also please add those codes to `virtual('password')`, to make sure the `hashedPassword` could be set correctly.

```
    if (passwordRegex.test(password)) {
         this.invalidate('password', 'Invalid password format');
    }else {
        this.hashedPassword = password;
    }
```

---

For the second question, `require('../models/User');` must be invoked before `mongoose.model()` to make sure the `User.js` is parsed firstly, and the `User` could be added into `mongoose.model` in `User.js`. So in `user.js` could find this `User` model from mongoose. JavaScript is an *interpreted programming language*, so we should tell the JS engine the file parsed order in this way.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer, I tried with your code and the virtual is well called (the .set code is executed) but the .invalidate doesn't persist till the .save for the parent. It still doesn't stop the validation. Any idea ?

Comment: @grll, Per this code `if (passwordRegex.test(password)) {
         this.invalidate('password', 'Invalid password format');
    }else {
        this.hashedPassword = password;
    }`, if the password is invalid, then `hashedPassword` cannot be set, and `hashedPassword` is required, so the required validation will be triggered. so no data will be saved to db. Could you please give me more information about your issue?

Comment: @grll, the first param of `validate` should be `path` in the schema, please try `this.invalidate('hashedPassword', 'Invalid password format');`

Comment: in fact the problem is that: if I call: var password = new Password({password: 'asdfwe32113'}); I can see with: console.log( password.$__.validationError.errors['hashedPassword']); that my validation error is here and working but as soon as I put this variable password in user.password it seems to disappear...

Comment: @grll, the `password` is just one virtual path of schema, whereas the `invalidate()` should pass the real path `hashedPassword` to it..

Comment: Thank you for your help, I put hashedPassword in invalidate() path but it still doesn't persist when I call user.password = password;

Comment: @grll, I am afraid you missunderstand the virtual meanings? the `password` is virtual field of schema, it does not need to be saved to db. whereas `hashedPassword` is the real field which saved into the db. The `password` is alias of `hashedPassword`. Hope I make self clearly. or am I misunderstand you?

Comment: The virtual is temporary yes, and hashedPassword will be saved. when I said user.password = password; earlier I meant: var password = new Password({ password: 'abcd1234'}); user.password = password; I know this is very messy sorry about that...

Comment: I have updated my code user.js to show you where it fails (see code comments)

Comment: alright thank you very much for your explanation just a last question how would you do then to invalidate UserSchema when it saves knowing that the validation error is in PasswordSchema ? my workaround is that: user.password.$__.validationError = password.$__.validationError; but it really doesn't look clean..

Comment: @grll, new answer has been updated... please check it.

Comment: Ok perfect your solution works the only problem in your code is that when you call Regex.test() you call it on v which is already hashed password. You need to call it on this._password. But otherwise it's working perfectly thanks a lot for your help !